# AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'show' for text file in spark databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, sql
from pyspark.sql import Row


text_file = sc.textFile('/FileStore/tables/data.txt').show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`sc.textFile` doesn't return a dataframe

RDD's don't have show()

You can collect() or take(10) to return a list that you can print

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use `spark.read.text('/FileStore/tables/data.txt').show()`, where `spark.read.text` returns a dataframe that can be `.show()`ed.